# How to Change the Response of the API in OnActionExecuted method of Controller in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

`Json` response:

```
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Value": 10,
    "User": null
}
```

I need to change the `User` value in each response in `OnActionExecuted` method.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
      var response = context.Result;
}
```

But unable to read the Result and Update details.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do some casting, I think. This code needs some error handling but otherwise demonstrates what you want:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Value = 10
        };
        return Ok(vm);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        var result = context.Result as OkObjectResult;
        var vm = result.Value as ViewModel;
        vm.User = "ardalis";
    }
}
```

The result:

```
{"id":1,"value":10,"user":"ardalis"}
```

Comment: Thank you ssmith. The model class varied in each response. I can solved  using dynamic variable.